# How to preserve space and special chars in filename when autostoring files in s3?

Tags: uploadcare

I configured a s3 bucket to automatically backup all the files from uploadcare. But the files that are backed up doesn't have the same name and the name is devoid of spaces and special chars.

For example, If I upload "My Resume.pdf" through uploadcare, I am seeing "My Resume.pdf" in cdn but "MyResume.pdf" in s3. It is very difficult this way to map the files between CDN and S3.

Any options to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we have to strip special and whitespace characters from *actual file that is saved on a disk* during upload process.
If we do not do that - all sorts of bad things happen.

Original file name is accessible via [REST API](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/rest/#file).

If you want to map file on Uploadcare CDN to a file backed up to your S3 bucket - you should use UUID for this, not filename (please answer in a comment or update the question, the reason if this doesn't work for you).

Comment: this is kind of crazy... it also causes big problems for us. we want to keep our filenames consistent. removing spaces, i suppose i could live with, but dashes, too?

Comment: @RyanWinchester, contact Uploadcare support and we'll help you out. StackOverflow is not a  right place for these things.